# How to make SASS/SCSS Module works with Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

I've installed [SASS/SCSS](http://drupal.org/project/sass) module within drupal seven... There is no configuration page apart from activating debug, and development mode. So, I thought there will be no other configuration needed. I've created my `.sass` files in the css directory... but nothing happens...

Could anyone helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you installed the PHamlP library or not and from your question description, it sounds like that is the problem -- it needs this to actually render your .sass files. From the readme:

```
1. Create a folder inside the SASS module (sites/all/modules/sass) and name it phamlp
2. Download PHamlP_3.2.zip from http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/downloads/list
3. Extract its contents to the phamlp folder you just created
4. Once you have installed/enabled the module you can visit admin/settings/sass where you can
configure various settings surrounding the behavior of this module.
```

Comment: did you try the above instructions? is sass/scss now working?

Comment: i have the same issue,  i did all the above , but the link is not working (admin/settings/sass). and including .scss files from the theme.info file has no effect

Comment: if the menu link is not working you should check that your user has the correct permissions and then flush your cache to rebuild the menu