# How to make sass/scss module work with omega theme?

Tags: 7, theming

When installing [sass/scss module](http://drupal.org/project/sass), and followed [readme instructions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/how-to-make-sass-scss-module-works-with-drupal-7)... then nothing happens. Is there any clue for this ?

Comment: What's supposed to happen?

Comment: When a `css` file is called, the `sass` file in the same directory and with the same name should be rendered in the `css` file.

Comment: What have you installed to watch the SASS folders in your theme, compass or something else?

Comment: You might find some general help on Omega+SASS [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/206148)

Comment: nothing, it should work as is because it uses phamlp... it works using `scss` and other themes than omega.

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't used the SCSS module before. I just have a program watching a specific set of folders under my theme which are compiled to the theme's CSS folder whenever they're changed. Drupal doesn't need to get involved that way and it's one less module installed. Would that be an option?

Comment: would be, but whenever it works with `scss` on other themes, using other program will become messy... better use other drupal module for `sass`. I've made some research in the  sass module code... it maybe not hard to add the possibility to use `sass`, as I read in its code.

Comment: If you do manage to solve it please post back here, I'm sure that will be very helpful to someone in the future :)

Comment: I've created this issue in the last couple days... but It was urgent to me... so I studied the code and added a patch [http://drupal.org/node/1911800](http://drupal.org/node/1911800). PS: Anyone seeing this patch, please test it and add comment in the issue.